# How to animate in while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate each DIV one by one using a while loop. but 
there are i am  facing a issue. while loop variable generate the number of series as i can get that in alert box.but when i use the while loop increment variable in .eq() function it not working as increment animate Div one by one.

..Jitu

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function BoxAnimate(){
 var count= 1;
  while( count < 9){
   //alert(count);
   $(".animation").eq(count).animate({
   left:"500px"
   });
   count++;
  }
 }

 BoxAnimate();
});
```

```css
.animation { background:red; 
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:30px;
  height:150px; 
  width:150px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:150px;
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ani-wrp">
     <div class="animation"> 1 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 2 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 3 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 4 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 5 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 6 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 7 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 8 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: div with 1 is not animating. Is that the issue you are facing?
Better try to initialize counter with 0.

Comment: You don't need to use any type of loop for this - please see my answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (also made a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hqm4bavw/2/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function BoxAnimate(){
 var count= 0;
  while( count < 9){
   //alert(count);
   $(".animation").eq(count).stop(true, true).delay(1000*count).animate({
    left:"500px"
   });
   count++;
  }
 }

 BoxAnimate();
});
```

```css
.animation { background:red; 
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:30px;
  height:150px; 
  width:150px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:150px;
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ani-wrp">
     <div class="animation"> 1 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 2 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 3 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 4 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 5 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 6 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 7 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 8 </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

> The usefulness of the .stop() method is evident when we need to
>   animate an element on mouseenter and mouseleave. In your case is not
>   mandatory.  Regarding the delay method, here you multiply the time of
>   delay with each loop with your count. So you will have 1000*1, 1000*2, 1000*3. There will be 1 second between each animation.

You can find more about these methods [here](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Comment: This one is prefect..!

But can you explain to me this code ( .stop(true, true).delay(1000*count) ).
To   extend  my knowledge ..!

Comment: @jitujahagirdar, I've added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`eq()` in jquery is 0 based change `var count= 1;` to `var count= 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something you haven't mentioned, you don't need to use a while loop at all. As each box has the same class, jQuery will target all of them at the same time:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function BoxAnimate(){
     $(".animation").animate({
   left:"500px"
  });
 }

 BoxAnimate();
});
```

```css
.animation { background:red; 
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:30px;
  height:150px; 
  width:150px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:150px;
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ani-wrp">
     <div class="animation"> 1 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 2 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 3 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 4 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 5 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 6 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 7 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 8 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better and clean approach would be using [each api of jquery](https://api.jquery.com/each/) rather than while loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".animation").each(function(){
         $(this).animate({
      left:"500px"
  });
    });

});
```

```css
.animation { background:red; 
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:30px;
  height:150px; 
  width:150px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:150px;
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ani-wrp">
     <div class="animation"> 1 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 2 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 3 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 4 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 5 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 6 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 7 </div>
  <div class="animation"> 8 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But its not move one by one. its select all "animation" div at the same  time